# How to sort the major diagonal of the matrix?

Tags: c

I am confused about getting the sort of the major diagonal of the matrix.
Here is my code:

```
void sortDiagonal(int a[][50], int row, int col)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        int sm = a[i][i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < col; j++) {
            if (sm > a[j][j]) {
                sm = a[j][j];
                a[j][j] = a[i][i];
                a[i][i] = sm;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

It seems like this code only works with a square matrix.
So I want it to work with a non-square matrix.

Comment: How would you define the diagonal of a *non*-square matrix?

Comment: first row (1 2 3 ) second row (4 5 6) -->> the diagonal of a non square matris  (1 5) (2 6)

Comment: Presumably, you need to define `int ub = (col < row) ? col : row);` and put the upper bound on the loops to `ub` instead of `col` or `row`?

Comment: If you are using a C compiler that supports variable-length arrays (a feature added in C99), you can change the function signature to `void sortDiagonal(int rows, int cols, int array[rows][cols])`.  Then you are no longer stuck with using arrays with a second dimension of 50 as you are at the moment.

Comment: Based on : https://www.mathdoubts.com/main-diagonal-rectangular-matrix/

The major diagonal for example matrix with first row (1,2,3) second row (4,5,6) should be only (1,5) That's it.

I think for that your code should ideally work provided that if you follow Jonathan's answer of checking the bound value in loop.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in comments:

```
void sortDiagonal(int rows, int cols, int array[rows][cols])
{
    int ub = (cols > rows) ? rows : cols;
    for (int i = 0; i < ub; i++)
    {
        int sm = array[i][i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < ub; j++)
        {
            if (sm > array[j][j])
            {
                sm = array[j][j];
                array[j][j] = array[i][i];
                array[i][i] = sm;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Test code used:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Which heaader? */
extern void sortDiagonal(int rows, int cols, int array[rows][cols]);

void sortDiagonal(int rows, int cols, int array[rows][cols])
{
    int ub = (cols > rows) ? rows : cols;
    for (int i = 0; i < ub; i++)
    {
        int sm = array[i][i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < ub; j++)
        {
            if (sm > array[j][j])
            {
                sm = array[j][j];
                array[j][j] = array[i][i];
                array[i][i] = sm;
            }
        } 
    }
}

static void dump_matrix(const char *tag, int rows, int cols, const int matrix[rows][cols]);

int main(void)
{
    /* Created by: gen_matrix -H 999 -L 100 -c 4 -r 3 -n matrix1 -w 3 -i */
    /* Random seed: 0x585FCC76 */
    int matrix1[3][4] =
    {
        { 715, 442, 126, 354, },
        { 559, 902, 367, 190, },
        { 296, 513, 384, 679, },
    };
    /* Created by: gen_matrix -H 999 -L 100 -c 3 -r 4 -n matrix2 -w 3 -i */
    /* Random seed: 0x10EA3E2A */
    int matrix2[4][3] =
    {
        { 599, 712, 850, },
        { 214, 188, 815, },
        { 706, 195, 984, },
        { 126, 832, 729, },
    };
    /* Created by: gen_matrix -H 999 -L 100 -c 4 -r 4 -n matrix3 -w 3 -i */
    /* Random seed: 0xD37A4A95 */
    int matrix3[4][4] =
    {
        { 146, 999, 247, 438, },
        { 911, 582, 571, 915, },
        { 541, 776, 372, 191, },
        { 255, 816, 848, 187, },
    };

    dump_matrix("matrix1 - unsorted", 3, 4, matrix1);
    sortDiagonal(3, 4, matrix1);
    dump_matrix("matrix1 - sorted", 3, 4, matrix1);

    dump_matrix("matrix2 - unsorted", 4, 3, matrix2);
    sortDiagonal(4, 3, matrix2);
    dump_matrix("matrix2 - sorted", 4, 3, matrix2);

    dump_matrix("matrix3 - unsorted", 4, 4, matrix3);
    sortDiagonal(4, 4, matrix3);
    dump_matrix("matrix3 - sorted", 4, 4, matrix3);

    return 0;
}

static void dump_matrix(const char *tag, int rows, int cols, const int matrix[rows][cols])
{
    printf("%s (%dx%d):\n", tag, rows, cols);
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        const char *pad = "";
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            printf("%s%3d", pad, matrix[r][c]);
            pad = "  ";
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Test output:

```
matrix1 - unsorted (3x4):
715  442  126  354
559  902  367  190
296  513  384  679
matrix1 - sorted (3x4):
384  442  126  354
559  715  367  190
296  513  902  679
matrix2 - unsorted (4x3):
599  712  850
214  188  815
706  195  984
126  832  729
matrix2 - sorted (4x3):
188  712  850
214  599  815
706  195  984
126  832  729
matrix3 - unsorted (4x4):
146  999  247  438
911  582  571  915
541  776  372  191
255  816  848  187
matrix3 - sorted (4x4):
146  999  247  438
911  187  571  915
541  776  372  191
255  816  848  582
```